# Mocha invisible descriptions

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Experience issue with mocha tests. Somewhy, tests descriptions are invisible. I cannot select them with mouse, they're just invisible.

The mocha test-file:

```
const app = require('../../server');

const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Unit', function() {
  describe('server', function() {
    it('env should stay test', function() {
      expect(process.env.NODE_ENV).to.be.eq('test');
    });

    it('should set uptime', function() {
      expect(typeof Date.parse(global.app_started)).to.be.eq('number');
    });

    it('should set app status to DOWN', function() {
      expect(global.app_status).to.be.eq('DOWN');
    });
  });
});
```

The output is the following:
[image]

My environment:

```
node -v // 8.1.3
npm -v // 5.0.3
```

Appreciate any suggestions on the issue.

Comment: I've used Mocha for years. Never seen this before and cannot reproduce with the information you provide in your question. The way forward is to include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @Lazyexpert This looks like a terminal app configuration problem, maybe go to Terminal > Preferences?

Comment: @ehacinom good point, I'll check it as soon as I'll get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in the comments, this looks like a Terminal app configuration problem. You can change the colors for different kinds of shell output at Terminal > Preferences.

Comment: I was sure, if the problem is with colours - I could see the text, when I select it with mouse. Very strange behavior, as for me.